# Check if a list within the hashmap contains 2 values and only those 2 values

Tags: java, bukkit

How would I check if this hashmap contains 2 specific values if it contains anything else beside those 2 values it cancels the events. (2 values) per player the string is the identifer aka the players uniqueid. So if the player has 3 or more values in the hashmap it cancels the event.

```
HashMap<String, List<Material>> result = new HashMap<>();
List<Material> values = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: I've only tried if ( result.contains ) it works but it doesn't work how I want it to work.

Comment: What do you mean by "it cancels the events"? Could you share the code you use for filling the values in the map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check whether the list contains two specific `Material` enum's and only those two, you could check whether the list contains two elements (whether the length of the list is 2) and then compare each of those two elements to see whether they are the correct types. Example incomplete code:

```
if (result.containsKey(PLAYER_NAME) && result.get(PLAYER_NAME).size() == 2) {
    List<Material> list = result.get(PLAYER_NAME);
    Material first = list.get(0);
    Material second = list.get(1);
    if (first == Material.FIRST && second == Material.SECOND || first == Material.SECOND && second == Material.FIRST) {
        //Don't cancel the event
    }
}
```

PLAYER_NAME is the `String` name of the player, Material.FIRST and Material.SECOND are the two `Material`s you're checking for. Not sure if I correctly understood your question though.

Answer (score 1):

What I understood from the question, I wrote down in code.

The `compareTo()` method compares two `Material` objects and returns `0` if they are matching. Assumption-variable `result` is accessible to the method.

```
public boolean continueEvent(String playerId, List<Material> values)
{
   List<Material> mapValues=result.get(playerId);
   if( mapValues.size()!=2){
      return false;
   }
   else{
      if((mapValues.get(0).compareTo(values.get(0)==0 && mapValues.get(1).compareTo(values.get(1)==0) || (mapValues.get(0).compareTo(values.get(1)==0 && mapValues.get(1).compareTo(values.get(0)==0)){
         return true;
      else
         return false;
       }
   }
}
```

<sup>**Note:** Code mentioned above is illustration of logic. I haven't executed it. There may be syntactic error.</sup>